# CentOS 7 reboot error getting authority?

Tags: centos, reboot, d-bus

I'm trying to reboot the CentOS 7 after `yum update`, and getting the following error when I run `sudo reboot`.

> Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An SELinux policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient, 0 matched rules; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus) (g-dbus-error-quark, 9)

I also get the same error when I run `sudo service dbus start`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has to do with SELinux.

> An SELinux policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient, 0 matched rules; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)"

You can either try and deal with this or disable SELinux. It's generally advisable to *NOT* disable software that's attempting to make your system more secure, but if it's a desktop or not a production type of system, these are easier approaches to find more accepting.

To disable SELinux and put it into `permissive` mode:

```
$ getenforce
Enforcing

$ setenforce 0
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
```

To make this permanent you can edit this file, `/etc/selinux/config` and change the line `SELINUX=` so that it says either `permissive` or `disabled`. A reboot is required to pick up the change from this file.

#### / permissions

Another culprit that may lead to this scenario has to do with the root directory's permissions. There's a "solution" logged on Redhat's main solutions site titled: [What is "DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An SELinux policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient" ?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1990203).

The issue is this:

> Permissions on / have been set to 700 ; restoring to 555 solved the issue

The fix:

> Ensure permissions on / are 555 ; if not adjust them by chmod 555 /

You can further verify if this is your issue using the `abrt`. You'll typically see this message when you log into a system that's suffering from this misconfiguration:

```
ABRT has detected 1 problem(s). For more info run: abrt-cli list --since 1444824402
```

Investigating the ABRT failure:

```
$ abrt-cli list --since 1444824402
id 050f5a46e0749583aaf102958b2ab1cc976133d9
reason:         bus.py:122:__new__:DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An SELinux policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient, 0 matched rules; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
time:           Wed 14 Oct 2015 06:56:16 AM EDT
cmdline:        /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/bin/firewall-cmd --zone= --change-interface=eth0
package:        firewalld-0.3.9-11.el7
uid:            0 (root)
count:          2
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/Python-2015-10-14-06:56:16-905
Run 'abrt-cli report /var/spool/abrt/Python-2015-10-14-06:56:16-905' for creating a case in Red Hat Customer Portal

The Autoreporting feature is disabled. Please consider enabling it by issuing
'abrt-auto-reporting enabled' as a user with root privileges
```

systemd also reports this failure state:

```
$ systemctl --failed
UNIT                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
avahi-daemon.service      loaded failed failed Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
libstoragemgmt.service    loaded failed failed libstoragemgmt plug-in server daemon
ovirt-guest-agent.service loaded failed failed oVirt Guest Agent
postfix.service           loaded failed failed Postfix Mail Transport Agent
rngd.service              loaded failed failed Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon
systemd-logind.service    loaded failed failed Login Service
tuned.service             loaded failed failed Dynamic System Tuning Daemon

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

7 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

#### References

- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1990203
- [5.4.2. Disabling SELinux](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux-Disabling_SELinux.html)
- [Disabling SELinux](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/install_cdh_disable_selinux.html)

Comment: As posted in the original question, I get the "Error getting authority: Error initializing authority" when I run "sudo reboot" command.

Comment: @GihyeonPark `sudo shutdown -r now`?

Comment: sudo shutdown -r now get the following errors: Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An SELinux policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient, 0 matched rules; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive) interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus) (g-dbus-error-quark, 9)
Could not watch jobs: Connection reset by peer
Failed to open /dev/initctl: No such device or address
Failed to talk to init daemon.

Comment: I do have /dev/initctl

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 25 May 21 15:00 /dev/initctl -> /run/systemd/initctl/fifo

Comment: Permissions on / is already 555. and sudo systemctl --failed gives another error (Failed to list units: Connection reset by peer).